# What is the best way to add attic intake ventilation?

Tags: attic, ventilation

I have an old attic where the soffits aren't ventilated, and can't be because the soffits are a separate dead air space, not continuous with the attic. It currently has two turbine vents (one of which does largely nothing since it's lower than the other) as well as gable vents, which are original to the house.

What would be the best way to add intakes to balance the exhaust capacity I currently have. Not including the two gable vents, I should have about 2 sq.ft. of exhaust ventilation for the 300 sq.ft. attic, but without any intakes, they don't really do much.

Comment: How are the gable vents inadequate? Your issue is really about circulation to the outer region of the attic. I'd look at installing static roof vents down low if it's not an aesthetic concern.

Comment: The gable vents are located at the peak of the gable end. They were the original exhaust vents before the turbines were retrofitted (in what appears to be a misguided attempt to decrease attic temperatures). In this system, there's no intake low in the attic, so the gable end only provides intake ventilation for 1 foot at the peak of the attic

Comment: I was confused by the phrase "without any intakes". You have intakes, it's just that they're not ideally located. I'd consider blocking those from the inside and adding drip-edge venting or something similar.

Comment: @isherwood True, there *are* intakes, but they weren't designed as such, and function poorly in that role. Would you want to type out a full answer on this?

Comment: I'm reluctant without some information about your structure and project scope. Maybe post a photo or two.

Comment: @isherwood Will edit when I get home and can post a few pictures